# Unable to install Expo-CLI both with NPM and Yarn

Tags: expo

I've been trying to install expo-cli and keep encountering errors. I've tried `verifying npm cache` and also `clear cache` but the errors still pesist. I also tried using yarn. I'm running node v12, windows 10 on a 64bit OS.

any idea on how fix this issue?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>yarn global add expo-cli
yarn global v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi > topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi > hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi > topo > hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > @babel/polyfill@7.4.4:  As of Babel 7.4.0, this
package has been deprecated in favor of directly
including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
(needed to use transpiled generator functions):

  > import "core-js/stable";
  > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi > hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi > topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi > topo > hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/-/traveling-fastlane-linux-1.9.9.tgz: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:443
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/-/traveling-fastlane-darwin-1.9.9.tgz: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:443
warning multiyargs@1.0.0: The engine "yargs" appears to be invalid.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\\Users\\ismail\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v4\\npm-@expo-traveling-fastlane-darwin-1.9.9-88445052d4bfd0826f332f71a08f4402ad7ffdcd\\node_modules\\@expo\\traveling-fastlane-darwin\\.yarn-metadata.json'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\ismail\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

I think this might have to be platform specific issue.

Comment: could you try `npm install -g expo-cli`? It's sam error???

Comment: yes, still the same error. I reverted to `expo-cli@2.19.0` which had the same errors too but still completed the installation

Comment: Try changing the directory youre installing on.